# Select root in TreeView before first draw

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview

I have a TreeView with binded ItemsSource. I want to select my root(first) node. But ItemContainerGenerator has not generated any TreeViewItem objects yet.

Is there any nice way to select the items without using timers/threads and so on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved.**

In DataTemplate added binding to IsSelected property in my Model. 
So if i need to select some item, i set IsSelected property in my Model object, not in TreeView